# How to select collection instead of collection of collections in SqlToEntity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Suppose you have Role class, and each Role has a collection of Users. I want to select all users within specified collections. I do:

```
DataContext.Roles.Where(r=>r==r1||r==r2).Select(r=>r.Users);
```

But that returns me something like collection of collections of User objects, while I want a simple collection of User objects. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to flatten the results, it sounds like you want [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548748.aspx):

```
DataContext.Roles
           .Where(r => r == r1 || r == r2)
           .SelectMany(r => r.Users);
```

This is equivalent (in impact, not *quite* in expansion) to:

```
from r in DataContext.Roles
where r == r1 || r == r2
from user in r.Users
select user;
```